# Android ExoPlayer playing issue inside ViewPager

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-video-player

I have a Pager with list of videos' URIs. The issue is ExoPlayer don't playing videos after they were swiped forward and back. At first time videos play normally, but after swiping they don't. Any suggestions?

Page:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/videoMediaViewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_controls"
    app:resize_mode="fill"/>
```

Pager callback:

```
private val pageChangeListener = object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        viewModel.media.value?.get(position)?.let { media ->
            if (media.type == MediaType.Video)
                setVideoForPosition(position, Uri.parse(media.links.original))
        }
    }
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
}

private fun setVideoForPosition(position: Int, uri: Uri){
        binding.carouselView.containerViewPager.get(position).findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.videoMediaViewer)?.also {
            if (it.player == null) it.player = exoPlayer
            if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) exoPlayer.stop()
            exoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri), 0)
            exoPlayer.prepare()
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you swipe back to video already played does it give any kind of error for not playing?

Comment: I have the same problem. do you already have solution on this?

Comment: @RaymondBarrinuevo always set `it.player = exoPlayer` without condition. Also set `exoPlayer.prepare()` and then `exoPlayer.pause()`.